# how to encode char in 2-bits?

Tags: c++, c, hash

trying to implement a hash function for k-mers of DNA sequences, DNA sequence usually contains combination of four characters A,C,G,T.

And I found this [thread](https://www.biostars.org/p/8219/#8232) very interesting,

> I have used the simple map from A,C,G,T onto {00, 01, 10, 11} (in bits), allowing four bases encoded in a byte. You could then use hash(word) + hash(rc(word)), or any other symmetric function. This approach has the advantage that you can use the current hash to find the next hash; as you shift bases in and out of your k-mer, you shift bits in and out of your hash or hash constituents. This is the approach taken in sylamer, and it's pretty fast.

but I couldnt know how to encode a character in 2 bits, My question, is there any tutorial, library, function for mapping characters to bits?

Comment: Related link http://gedcom-parse.sourceforge.net/doc/encoding.html

Comment: Bit shifting and masking should suffice.

Comment: What is a relation between bits and characters? Your quoted text just says that A,C,G,T are presented as 00, 01, 10, 11 correspondingly. Even more, C and C++ don't operate with "characters", they operate with their integer representations.

Comment: thanks a lot @πάντα ῥεῖ, my real problem was finding the topic name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although A, C, G & T can be mapped arbitrarily onto 00, 01, 10, 11 -- or any other arrangment -- there's at least one mapping that falls out for practically free from ASCII codes, A, C, G & T -> 00, 01, 11, 10:

```
A 65 01000|00|1  0
C 67 01000|01|1  1
G 71 01000|11|1  3
T 84 01010|10|0  2
```

Conveniently, the arrangement can also work for RNA as the U nucleotide doesn't disturb the bit pattern when it replaces the DNA T nucleotide:

```
U 85 01010|10|1  2
```

To get from ASCII letter to bits, simply shift and mask:  (N >> 1) & 3

Again, what mapping you use is arbitrary, this is just an easy one to implement.

Given the above approach, let's write an encoder/decoder to pack a 32 base k-mer into a 64 bit number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define TWO_BIT_MASK (3)
#define BITS_PER_BYTE (8)
#define BIG_ENOUGH (1024)

uint64_t encode(char *original) {

    size_t length = strlen(original);

    assert(length * 2 == sizeof(uint64_t) * BITS_PER_BYTE);

    uint64_t result = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result = (result << 2) | ((original[i] >> 1) & TWO_BIT_MASK);
    }

    return result;
}

void decode(uint64_t encoded, char *decoded, bool rna_flag) {

    int i = sizeof(uint64_t) * BITS_PER_BYTE / 2;

    for (decoded[i--] = '\0'; i >= 0; i--, encoded >>= 2) {

        unsigned char byte = encoded & TWO_BIT_MASK;

        if (byte == 2) {
            byte = (rna_flag) ? 'U' : 'T';
        } else {
            byte = 'A' | (byte << 1);
        }

        decoded[i] = byte;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *segment = "GCCGTGCTAAGCGTAACAACTTCAAATCCGCG";

    printf("%s\n", segment);

    uint64_t binary = encode(segment);

    printf("%llu\n", binary);

    char string[BIG_ENOUGH];

    decode(binary, string, false);

    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
GCCGTGCTAAGCGTAACAACTTCAAATCCGCG
15543626420740950391
GCCGTGCTAAGCGTAACAACTTCAAATCCGCG
>
```

Comment: thanks @cdlane, Im gonna take some time trying to understand bit shifting and masking and ur implementation, thanks again for ur time :))

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
typedef enum { NB_A = 0, NB_C, NB_G, NB_T } Nucleobase;

Nucleobase nucleobase_encode(char n)
{
  n = tolower((unsigned char) n);
  switch(n)
  {
    case 'a': return NB_A;
    case 'c': return NB_C;
    case 'g': return NB_G;
    case 't': return NB_T;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then you can use the above to encode four bases into a single byte:

```
uint8_t encode_quad(char b0, char b1, char b2, char b3)
{
  return (nucleobase_encode(b3) << 6) | (nucleobase_encode(b2) << 4) |
   (nucleobase_encode(b1) << 2) | nucleobase_encode(b0);
}
```

This will encode the four bases like so:

```
b3 | b2 | b1 | b0
```

Comment: Optimized version if anyone needs to encode large sequences. https://github.com/linsalrob/EdwardsLab/blob/master/cpp/two-bit-optimized.c. I tried to add notes to explain the optimizations but that was too long for this comment block so drop me a note if you would like more details. John